# Asp.net Application wide event publishing

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to update another persons page from another page? ie what i am trying to do is... when a user updates a treeview with some data, i would like to broadcast the changes to any other user who is online and automatically update their treeview with the changes.

Is there some sort of pattern that i can have a look at to do this?

thanks yal...

Comment: please mention that you want it in asp .net or silverlight or any other technology

Answer (score 1):

In realtime? You would want to use JS polling or [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) techniques.

Heres a solution using silverlight and WCF Duplex http://blog.developers.ba/post/2009/02/25/Silverlight-chat-application-using-WCF-full-duplex.aspx

This looks awlright too http://code.google.com/p/aspcomet/ Should work with a JS client (see http://www.cometd.com/)